# struct X declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration

Tags: c, gcc, struct, makefile

This question has been asked before but non of the solution seemed to solve my problem.

I wrote a C library for college homework and wrote my own makefile for compiling.

**this is my first C code so I'm sorry if its a stupid question..

when I compile I get the following messages:

1.

`warning: ‘struct stud’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 void addGrade(char *id, int courseId, int gradeToAdd, struct stud* students);`

2.

```
error: unknown type name ‘stud’
void addIncome(char *id, char *date, int amount, stud* students);
```

^^2 happened when I didn't declare "struct stud" but only "stud" inside a method even though I typedef'ed it. 1 happened when i used the word struct before declaration.

each .c file has a .h file with all the declaration of its methods.
each struct is defined  once in the right .h file and all the .c files includes student.h .

*I'm compiling with gcc in Linux environment.

I added my code and makefile:

includes inside main:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "grades.h"
#include "income.h"
#include "student.h"

main(){
    return 0;
}
```

student.h:

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 20
#define MAX_LIST_LEN 10
#define MAX_NUM_STUDENTS 30

typedef struct stud{
    char sId[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char sName[MAX_STR_LEN];
    struct grade* sGrades; //both head of the lists
    struct income* sIncome;
    int sGradeLen;
    int sIncomeLen;
}stud;
```

makefile:

```
prog.o: main.o income.o grades.o student,o
    gcc -Wall main.o income.o grade.o student.o -o prog.o

main.o: ex2.c income.h grades.h student.h
    gcc -Wall -c ex2.c -o main.o

student.o: student.c student.h
    gcc -Wall -c student.c -o student.o

income.o: income.c income.h student.h
    gcc -Wall -c income.c -o income.o

grades.o: grades.c grades.h student.h
    gcc -Wall -c grades.c -o grades.o
```

I am not sure where my problem is and I will be grateful for help!

Comment: `addIncome` has no clue what `stud` is because `stud` is not reachable from `income.h`. Show your `income.h` and `income.c`

Comment: You need to put `#include "student.h"` before `#include "grades.h"`

Comment: @Barmar thank you, problem solved!